# Android Studio colors.xml

Tags: xml, android-studio

I have gradle 3.2.1 and whenever I make a new project gradle.build error shows in colors.xml file and following is in the `colors.xml` file.

> /* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
>   This class was automatically generated by the *gradle* plugin from the resource data it found.
>   It should not be modified by hand. /package androidx.v

And the error is:

> colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.